# How do you install a (x509 / pk12) certificate on ICS without users consent?

Tags: java, android, certificate, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

For an application I am developping, I need to be able to install CA and user certificates and private keys without his or hers concent.

I will have full system priviledges, and its fair to assume that the user will have a password before this happens. I will have the x509 if its a CA certificate or the pk12 if its a User certificate + private key file, and also the password if its the USer certificate + private key. I need to do this to be able to set up WPA-EAP wifi configurations automatically, and prefibly I want this to happen without the employees having to notice anything.

If anyone also know how to list all certificates that is installed, I would be very grateful.

I have checked throughout the day, and tested a bit with **keystore_cli** without success, and I have also read through the CertInstaller code without getting any wiser. Everything there is package-wide so I cannot call the methods directly, + it seems to send stuff further away to com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.CredentialStorage".

Any advice would be very great.

---

**EDIT** For those wondering, here is how I did it with the CA Certificates. The application needs to be able to run as the system user ( `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in android manifest ).

```
            // Android...why do you enjoy doing my life so difficult...
            try {
                Class<?> keyStoreClass = WifiConfiguration.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("android.security.KeyStore");

                Method getInstanceMethod = keyStoreClass.getMethod("getInstance");
                Object keyStore = getInstanceMethod.invoke(null);

                Log.d("DeviceManager", "Got keystore" + keyStore.toString());

                // Put(Key, Value)
                Method putCertificateMethod = keyStoreClass.getMethod("put", String.class, byte[].class);

                Log.d("DeviceManager", "Putting...");

                RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("/data/ca.crt", "r");
                byte[] b = new byte[(int)file.length()];
                file.read(b);
                byte[] cacert = b;

                Log.d("DeviceManager", "Certificate is bytes long: " + b.length);

                putCertificateMethod.invoke(keyStore, "CACERT_name", cacert);


            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately this is not possible on a stock device. Otherwise, any rogue app will be able to install CA certificates without user consent. If you have small set of devices, you might have to pre-provision them. As for PKCS#12 files, they are password protected so someone will need to enter the password.

Not sure what you mean by 'full system privileges', but if you can link your app with platform code and sign it with the system certificate, you can call `KeyChainService` methods directly. This will let you install certificates. Additionally, CA certificates are just stored as files, so you can copy them over to the right place. Some details here: http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2011/11/ics-credential-storage-implementation.html

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer and your brilliant articles. They helped me learn much more about the way this works.

First of all. By saying full sysstem priviledges I do indeed mean that the app will be signed with the system certificate. This is a device management solution for a company producing their own hardware and software, giving me full control over the android eco system.

I checked KeyChainService, and found the method `installCaCertificate(byte[] caCertificate)` there, which might be relevant. But it seems to only take the certificate as bytes, not caring of the alias. [cont..]

Comment: I need to be able to assign aliases as well, as this will be used for automatically transfering wifi configurations to a users device, prefibly without them knowing or caring. Now, for Wifi and WPA-EAP, the server can require CA certificates, and/or private cert+keys, so I need to be able to install all of these things. For CA Certificates, they will be installed in `/data/misc/keychain/cacerts-added` and in `/data/misc/keystore/`. I have transfered ca certificates successfully to the cacerts-added folder, and they show up in the installed certificates, but not on the Wifi list. [cont...]

Comment: This seems to require it to come in the `/data/misc/keystore` folder as well, as i see 1000_CACERT_ca there, and it will pop up in the WPA EAP list as well.

Comment: Right, the WiFi code is not Java, so it doesn't use the cacerts-added/ files. You need to use `android.security.KeyStore.put()` to install the cert and give it an alias. Look at `com.android.settings.CredentialStorage` for how to use it. Basically, you need to install using both `KeyChainService` (for Java's TrustManager, etc) and `KeyStore` (for the WiFi and VPN infrastructure).

Comment: First of all, thank you so much! I have been able to install a .crt CA certificate successfully using reflection on the `android.security.KeyStore.put()` method as the system user. That worked brilliantly. Then arises the question, how do  I do the same with the pk12 certificate? I will know the password, so the user shouldn't need to type that in.

Comment: See how the installer is doing it. It's essentially the same, only the prefix for certificates and keys is different. BTW, if you build your app using in the platform build tree, you can call `@hide`-n methods directly, no need to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

The following method will configure the WPA/EAP-TLS wifi configuration with CA certificate and User certificate. You can use it for other EAP configuration also.

```
public static void createEapConfig(Context context, String ssid, String password, boolean connectAutomatically, boolean hiddenNetwork,
                                   Integer eapMethod, Integer phase2, String identity, String anonymousIdentity, String caCertificateData,
                                   String clientCertificateData, String clientCertPass) {
    if (ssid == null || eapMethod == null) {
        return;
    }
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    boolean connect = connectAutomatically;
    boolean isWifiReceiverRegistered = false;
    try {
        Logger.logEnteringOld();

        WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
        config.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
        config.hiddenSSID = hiddenNetwork;//false; //hidden network is always set to false.
        config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        config.priority = 40;
        try {
            wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class).invoke(wifiManager, config, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.logError(e);
        }
        Settings.isWifiHotspotEnabled(false);
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

        if (connect) {
            lastActNetId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
            wifiManager.disableNetwork(lastActNetId);
            wifiManager.disconnect();
        }
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);

        // Set defaults
        if (phase2 == null) phase2 = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.NONE;
        if (identity == null) identity = "";
        if (anonymousIdentity == null) anonymousIdentity = "";
        if (caCertificateData == null) caCertificateData = "";
        if (clientCertificateData == null) clientCertificateData = "";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
            if (Util.isNullOrEmpty(password)) {
                config.enterpriseConfig.setPassword(password);
            }

            config.enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(eapMethod);

            if (phase2 != null) {
                config.enterpriseConfig.setPhase2Method(phase2);
            }
            if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(identity)) {
                config.enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(identity);
            }
            if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(anonymousIdentity)) {
                config.enterpriseConfig.setAnonymousIdentity(anonymousIdentity);
            }
            InputStream is = null;
            if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(caCertificateData)) {
                try {
                    byte[] decodedCaCert = Base64.decode(caCertificateData);
                    //is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/local-root(1).cer" );
                    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                    try {

                        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedCaCert);
                        X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);
                        config.enterpriseConfig.setCaCertificate(caCert);
                    } catch (CertificateException ex) {
                        Logger.logError(ex);
                    } finally {
                        if (is != null) {
                            is.close();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Logger.logError(t);
                }
            }
            if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(clientCertificateData) && !Util.isNullOrEmpty(clientCertPass)) {
                try {
                    byte[] decodedClientCert = Base64.decode(clientCertificateData);
                    KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
                    is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedClientCert);
                    //is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/createdDERCert(1).pfx");
                    p12.load(is, clientCertPass.toCharArray());
                    Enumeration aliases = p12.aliases();
                    for (String alias : Collections.list(aliases)) {

                        if (alias == null) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) p12.getKey(alias, clientCertPass.toCharArray());
                        if (privateKey == null) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        X509Certificate clientCert = (X509Certificate) p12.getCertificate(alias);

                        if (clientCert != null) {
                            config.enterpriseConfig.setClientKeyEntry(privateKey, clientCert);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Logger.logError(t);
                } finally {
                    if (is != null) {
                        try {
                            is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int networkId = -1;
        networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(config);

        wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration();

        if (connect) {
            wifiManager.reconnect();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            Settings.cntxt.registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, filter);
            isWifiReceiverRegistered = true;
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        if (NetworkStateReceiver.activeConnection(Settings.cntxt)) {
            lastActNetId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.logError(ex);
    } finally {
        // unregister wifi state receiver
        if (connect && isWifiReceiverRegistered) {
            isWifiReceiverRegistered = false;
            Settings.cntxt.unregisterReceiver(wifiReceiver);
        }
    }

    Logger.logEnteringOld();
}
```